# Make a simple XSS vulnerable site

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I've been trying to figure this out all night and I've searched everywhere and I'm still confused.  All I'm trying to do is create a very simple website that is vulnerable to a XSS attack like:

```
'<script>alert('xss')</script>'.
```

Can anyone give me a little code snippet of a form and how it could be used so that's it's vulnerable to XSS?

Comment: I think you shold ask for the many ways of XSS vulnerabilities and not for some "little code snippet". People tend to downvote questions asking for code.

Answer (score 0):

Rails casts has a recent episode on security that demonstrates XSS, you might give that a go http://railscasts.com/episodes/178-seven-security-tips

Answer (score 0):

In what programming language?

if all you need is a vulnerable app to play with there is an intentionally vulnerable app up at http://www.insecurelabs.org, and you find some context based xss at http://www.insecurelabs.org/task 
You could always take a look at hacmebank or one of the live CDs like the OWASP live CD or SamiraiWTF.

Comment: Thanks, I actually got it now...I've come to the conclusion that before I can really learn security I need to learn how to make things before I can break them, so that's why I was trying to make a vulnerable site.

Comment: If you're interested, here's a big list of intentionally vulnerable sites that you can use to practice on: https://www.bonkersabouttech.com/security/40-plus-list-of-intentionally-vulnerable-websites-to-practice-your-hacking-skills/392